# Appropriate Listener for SWT Text

Tags: java, swt, listener

I have a JFace dialog which contains SWT Text and a button . Initially when the dialog is opened the button should be disabled, and when I click on the `Text` and as long as the caret position of the `Text` is visible button should be enabled.

These are the listeners i am using :

```
text.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) 
        {
            testButton.setEnabled(true);

        }   

    });

    text.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) 
        {
            testButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) 
        {

        }
    });
```

Am I using the appropriate listeners? Please suggest

Comment: So you want the `Button` to be disabled when the `Text` loses focus? If so, you would never be able to press the `Button`...

Comment: yes... but when i click on the Text i am enabling the button, then when i move away from Text , i still have the button enabled and im able to press it ... and as soon as the button is clicked , button gets disabled

Comment: Ok, so the button is disabled, then you click on the text and the button gets enabled (even if no text is entered) and when you click the button it disables itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should be what you want:

```
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    text.addListener(SWT.FocusIn, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

Initially, the `Button` is disabled. It will be enabled once the `Text` gaines focus. The `Button` will be disabled again after it was pressed.